# Cardano-Wallet server won't restore my wallet through mnemonic_sentence

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, linux

When I try to restore a users wallet through cardano-wallet (testnet) I get this payload using the `[POST] /wallets` endpoint

```
{
  "code": "wallet_already_exists",
  "message": "This operation would yield a wallet with the following id: 8209f39a872faa51a63c0f7bb8d748067cf7b2b0 However, I already know of a wallet with this id."
}
```

The following payload I send is the `name`,`mnemonic_sentence` & `passphrase` with the same arguments I gave it while creating the wallet. I even went as far as to change the `name` & `passphrase` but I still get the same `wallet_already_exists` error.

```
{
  "name": "Recovery Wallet",
  "mnemonic_sentence": [
    <15 KEYS>
  ],
  "passphrase": "wallet_pass_01"
}
```

I read that `Cardano-Wallet` should lookup a wallet and return its funds when a mnemonic_sentence derives a wallet that already exists. As you can see this isn't working for me & I don't see how I can force a recovery.

Comment: Sounds like the wallet was created successfully. Can you see the addresses of the wallet? Use something like `/wallets/{walletId}/addresses` which would be `wallets/8209f39a872faa51a63c0f7bb8d748067cf7b2b0/addresses` in your case. Then check address balances. Or you could delete the wallet and restore it again if you want.

Comment: @MC_Brisbane-JUSTPool Yes! I actually did that & came across something interesting. Since `cardano-wallet` is a stateful services the DB checks to see if a wallet was created already by itself, resulting in a DB lookup for that ID. If there is no ID in the DB & on the cardano-network then it'll create a wallet for you.

Now if you want to restore a wallet that your instance of `cardano-wallet` has created then it'll throw the `wallet_already_exists` error. So the solution is either me having to create my own cardano server to manage keys or I have to wipe the `cardano-wallet` db each time :(

Comment: Ok that is interesting behaviour, got link to the info? Are you using the latest wallet version? cardano-wallet version v2022-07-01 was only released recently so will have a heap of changes/fixes relating to compatibility with cardano-node 1.35.0.

Comment: Let me look into this, apparently I've been using v2022-04-27. I'm going to update my container & then get back to you on this, if the error still persists then I'll create my own server to talk directly  to the cardano-node & bypass cardano-wallet

Answer (score 0):

Summary from comments:

Suggested for OP to check they are is using the latest cardano-wallet version v2022-07-01.

OP noted they are using v2022-04-27 so will update and report back.